# Add Checkbox Column to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i´m trying to add a checkboxcolum in a datagrid control in WPF.

I´ve done this in Windows.Forms and it works very well.

So now i want to write my new program in WPF for the future.

My way that i want to do:
The Data will come from a Database as a Dataset.

Some fields have values that i want to display as a checkbox.
Now i´ve set the datagrid autocreatecolumn true, the data will be displayed.

Now i want to delete the column that displays the value and will add a checkbox column.

Is that possible or should i create the columns via datatemplate?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with AutoGenerateColumn turned on....  You have to define each column individually

Comment: Ok. That isn't the answer that i want to hear. Is it possible to create datagrid columns at runtime by getting the db fieldtype from the query.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

WPF DataGrid provides a feature called AutoGenerateColumns that automatically generates column according to the public properties of your data objects. It generates the following types of columns based on the type of the value, and you dont have to do anything.:

```
1. TextBox columns for string values
2. CheckBox columns for boolean values
3. ComboBox columns for enumerable values
4. Hyperlink columns for Uri values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscibe to `AutoGeneratingColumn` event and change the column that is being generated:

```
public MyWindow(){
       myDataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += AutoGeneratingColumnHandler;
}

private void AutoGeneratingColumnHandler(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) {
        var bindingPath = ((e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding).Path.Path;
        if (bindingPath == "MYPATH") {
              var checkBoxColumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
              checkBoxColumn.Binding = new Binding(bindingPath);
              e.Column = checkBoxColumn;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Vale! It works very well. I think for columnbox this will be the same code but with DataGridColumnBoxColumn.